# how to open instagram in textView?

Tags: android

in a part of my app , I want to open Instagram app when sb comment an instagram profile with '@' or in other ways like using below link:
instagram://user?username=
problem with this link is that autoLink didn't recognize it as a link.
it's a part of textView in a recyclerView,how can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to filter your text using regex for desired pattern and then you can use linkify to handle clicks on those patterns. You can [start here](http://www.indelible.org/ink/android-linkify/)

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem using the link :

```
instagram.com/_u/<user>
```

instead of :

```
instagram.com/<user>
```